# Using mtl's MonadReader with haskeline has type error

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskeline

I want use `InputT (ReaderT Int IO) a` with `MonadReader Int`.

I write below code to make instance MonadReader on InputT

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module HaskelineMonadReader where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import System.Console.Haskeline

instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (InputT m) where
    ask = lift ask
    local = mapInputT . local

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "HI"
```

But I get this type error.

```
HaskelineMonadReader.hs:11:13:
Couldn't match type ‘m0 a0 -> m0 a0’ with ‘forall b. m b -> m b’
Expected type: (m0 a0 -> m0 a0) -> InputT m a -> InputT m a
  Actual type: (forall b. m b -> m b) -> InputT m a -> InputT m a
Relevant bindings include
  local :: (r -> r) -> InputT m a -> InputT m a
    (bound at HaskelineMonadReader.hs:11:5)
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘mapInputT’
In the expression: mapInputT . local
```

How can I fix this error.

Full source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/majecty/1ee93a2bb4b1e8ed421fd3bf15be8ec6)

Comment: It would help if you would supply a complete example with import statements.

Comment: @ErikR I add gist link.
I can get the error by `runhaskell HaskelineMonadReader.hs`

Comment: @melpomene I update full error message.

Comment: Your code is morally OK, but copes with a general typing rule: when instantiating a type variable, a polymorphic type `forall a. ...` can not be used. Above, the composition operator `(.)` is used for a rank2 function `mapInputT` which expects a polytyped argument. This requires that one of the type variables of `(.)` is istantiated by such polytype -- but alas this is forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module HaskelineMonadReader where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import System.Console.Haskeline

instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (InputT m) where
    ask = lift ask
    local f = mapInputT (local f)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "HI"
```

**Update**

Here is the error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘m0 a0 -> m0 a0’
               with ‘forall b. m b -> m b’

Expected type: (m0 a0 -> m0 a0)       -> InputT m a -> InputT m a
Actual type:   (forall b. m b -> m b) -> InputT m a -> InputT m a
```

So it appears that the expected type is more general because the `m0` does *not* have to be the same as `m`. In the actual type the `m` in `m b` must be the same as the `m` in `m a`.